# React Native TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating 'u()(o).then')

Tags: javascript, react-native, typeerror, crashlytics, react-native-sentry

Sentry Error Screenshot Code Reference

[image]

I am getting this issue reported on firebase crashlytics and sentry from my production app. 5 events and 4 users have been affected out of 100 users. I'm not able to reproduce this issue and also not able to determine its cause. As per the stack trace it looks like it's happening in the AppRegistry.js react native module inside node modules.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'u()(o).then')
  at apply(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:258:20)
  at __callFunction(node_modules/react- 
  native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:414:27)
  at fn(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:113:12)
  at __guard(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:365:9)
  at value(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:10)
  at value([native code])
```

Comment: You can look into how to use Source Map to find the line number in the JS code like they have explained for Sentry [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/sourcemaps/). YOu can do the same thing for Crashlytics.

Comment: Thanks @Nishant for the reply, but I thought sentry does it by default, that's why I integrated sentry along with crashlytics as crashlytics is not so very helpful with JS stack traces.

Comment: Sentry does. Did you try putting and intentional Error and see if that works. If the Error originated from a library / or on the native side -- then, I guess you won't see the code reference, but otherwise, Sentry works pretty nicely (assuming build had pushed to Sentry servers successfully).

Comment: Yeah I did tested sentry and it's working just fine for other errors, showing proper JS stack traces and even code references, but sadly not for this one. I think maybe it's happening natively or within any module on some specific devices.